# Get list of all instants between 2 instants in Scala

Tags: java, scala, date

I want to get a list of all instants between today and (today - 15) days.

I am understanding I might need to you use LazyList if scala, but I am not so familiar with the syntax since I am new. The java equivalent seems to be

```
  Set <Instant> allPossibleDates =
    Stream.iterate(today, date -> date.minus(1, ChronoUnit.DAYS))
      .limit(numDates)
      .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

What is the equivalent for this in Scala?

Comment: `val allPossibleDates = Stream.iterate(Instant.now(), (date: Instant) => date.minus(1, ChronoUnit.DAYS))
                .limit(15).collect(Collectors.toSet());
println(allPossibleDates)`. Check [here](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/6cv8TodOQvejHYaODCNMLg).

Comment: Stream is deprecated in Scala

Comment: What Arvind posted is just Scala syntax around java methods. But yes, Scala's `Stream` was renamed to `LazyList` in Scala 2.13

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `LazyList` companion object defines an `iterate` method that lets you define a sequence in terms of a starting point and a step operation (Note: `Iterator`'s companion defines a similar method):

```scala
def iterate[A](start: => A)(f: (A) => A): LazyList[A]
```

In fact it looks essentially the same as the Java version except that the `start` and `f` arguments appear in separate parameter lists. Pepper in Scala's syntax sugar for anonymous functions (using `_` to represent the function argument), you can do

```scala
val today = Instant.now() // or whatever
LazyList
  .iterate(today) { _.minus(1, ChronoUnit.DAYS) }
  .take(15) // equivalent to `limit` in Java
  .to(Set) // equivalent to `collect(...)`
```

Also note that LazyList defines an overload of `iterate` which takes a limit, which would replace the `.take`:

```scala
LazyList
  .iterate(today, 15) { _.minus(1, ChronoUnit.DAYS) }
  .to(Set)
```

Note that you could do `.foreach { instant => /* ... */ }` instead of `.to(SomeCollectionCompanion)` to iterate the contents without allocating the memory for a collection.